# In Github, is it possible to delete a folder without having to delete each file manually, using the site, not the command line?

Tags: github

I want to delete the entire folder, not every individual file as it could get tedious. I know how to delete files from a folder and make the folder disappear after everyone is deleted.

Comment: Just delete the folder, stage, and commit the changes? I suspect there is something else that is not being understood here.

Comment: Dude, in GIT folders does not exist. But you can simply git rm -r directory